# How to get resource folder in pycharm for python programming

Tags: python, image, resources

I'm trying to copy image from my local disk to resource folder in pycharm, I could see there is no resource folder in 'src' or 'test'. As we get the 'resource' folder in IntelliJ by default, I would like to have a resource folder in pycharm for python programming, please let me know, is there any possibility/way ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? you can create any directory wherever you want and name it like you want.

Comment: Thank you, I will try creating directory and continue my work. Hope that works for me.

Comment: I have created Resource directory manually, and tried using the root path in my project. It was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I have created Resource directory manually, and tried using the root path in my project. It was successful.